# How to store shapes in arrays?

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to display a Shape in an array in a view, how should I do it, thanks for any help!

```
struct ScenesModel: Hashable {
    static func == (lhs: ScenesModel, rhs: ScenesModel) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(name)
    }
    
    let path: Shape
    let name: String
    var selected: Bool = false
    
}
```

```
var scenesArray:[ScenesModel] = [
    ScenesModel(path: Test(), name: "scene1", selected: false),
    ScenesModel(path: Test2(), name: "scene2", selected: true)
]
```

```
struct Test: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        Path { path in
            let width = rect.size.width
            let height = rect.size.height
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.32692*width, y: 0.99145*height))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.26581*width, y: 0.8094*height))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.19701*width, y: 0.62991*height))
        }
    }
}

struct Test2: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        Path { path in
            let width = rect.size.width
            let height = rect.size.height
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.32692*width, y: 0.99145*height))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.26581*width, y: 0.8094*height))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.19701*width, y: 0.62991*height))
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried a lot of things, but I get all kinds of errors, so hopefully I can put the shape inside the array, thanks!

Comment: Storing references to `Views` or `Shapes` is going to be an uphill battle. Instead, why not store something (like an `enum`) that describes which shape you want to draw and then draw that in your `View`?

Comment: @jnpdx Thanks! At first, I wanted to use enum to implement it, but it is not intuitive to use enum to describe the data structure. Using enum also faces the difficulty of returning different structs, which has been confusing for a long time.

Comment: I don't know what "Using enum also faces the difficulty of returning different structs" means

Comment: @jnpdx Sorry, there is something wrong with my description.   enum ScenesModel {
    case t1, t2
    
    func getShape() -> Shape {
        switch self {
        case .t1:
            return Test()
        case .t2:
            return Test2()
        }
    }
}
This is how I implemented it, can you help me further?
Now xcode reports an error, Protocol 'Shape' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in the comments, rather than trying to store references to `Shape`s or `View`s, it's probably better to store a model that you can then dynamically create the `Shape` from later.

Here's an example:

```
struct SceneModel : Identifiable {
    var id : UUID = UUID()
    var name : String
    var selected : Bool
    var sceneType : SceneType
    
    enum SceneType {
        case test, test2
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    let scenesArray:[SceneModel] = [
        SceneModel(name: "scene1", selected: false, sceneType: .test),
        SceneModel(name: "scene2", selected: true, sceneType: .test2),
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(scenesArray) { scene in
            Text(scene.name)
            switch scene.sceneType {
            case .test:
                Test()
            case .test2:
                Test2()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this answered your question, please consider marking it as correct/accepted